# OpenLayers-v5: How to get WFS features before vector layer is visible

Tags: openlayers, wfs, vector-layer

I expected a WFS call to be made when a Vector Layer was added to the map, but it doesn't happen until the layer is marked as visible.

Here is how I'm currently creating my vector layers. The `visible` param is initially marked as false via `layer.checked`

```
function createVectorLayer (layer, zIndex) {
  const source = new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    url: function (extent) {
      return `${process.env.GEOSERVER_URL}/wfs?service=WFS&version=${process.env.WFS_VERSION}&request=GetFeature&typename=${layer.name}&outputFormat=application/json`
    }
  })
  return new VectorLayer({
    source,
    style: VectorStyle,
    opacity: layer.opacity,
    visible: layer.checked,
    zIndex
  })
}
```

I then add them to the map via the standard method:
`map.addLayer(vectorLayer)`

The problem is that until I update the layer's visibility via
`vectorLayer.setVisible(true)` the wfs call made to the `url` defined in `VectorSource` won't be made and therefore the layer has no features which is causing problems.

Again, I assumed would be that the wfs call would be made when the Layer was added to the map and not on the condition of its visibility.

I haven't been able to find anything in the docs that explains this, so I could use some help/information.

How can I get a vector features (via wfs call) before the layer is marked visible?

> app-specific information

- I'm creating a feature search that sets the map's center to that feature's coordinates
- but, if the layer is not 'visible' yet (the user just opened the map and everything is at default settings), the layer has no features to search from

  - I can then set the layer as visible on search, but then the wfs call is made in the background and I have no way to listen to it's return. I could listen to a layer's `change` event but that's irregardless of the main question of:
  - how (if possible) can I get a layer's features via wfs before the layer is visible

Comment: Just an aside, I see you have version number as a variable, but then use 'typename' as as if it's independent of version number, it's not. For version 2 it should be typenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably by using opacity instead of visibility

```
new VectorLayer({
    source,
    style: VectorStyle,
    opacity: layer.checked * layer.opacity,
    visible: true,
    zIndex
  })
```

Alternatively if you have a fully opaque base layer you could hide other layers behind it by reducing their zIndex, or you you have a visible layer but keep the features hidden by setting an empty style.

Comment: yes, that is technically a way to do it so I'll mark it as correct, but as far as my app goes that would mean creating an inconsistency between the user's visibility/order/opacity settings :(